# redirection with nginx is not working.

Tags: docker, spring-boot, nginx, dockerfile, load-balancing

I am still learning **nginx** and trying to do a simple redirect with nginx for my spring boot application.I have managed to setup everything using docker this is my **docker file** and my **default.conf** file.

**DockerFile**

```
  RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y nginx
  RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
  ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**default.conf file inside /etc/nginx/conf.d**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  default_server;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/testing;
    }
  }
```

I am executing a **.sh** file from the **Dockerfile** which will start the nginx service and start the jar file.

i cant figure out what am i doing wrong in here, is my configurations wrong or should i delete **nginx.conf** file and replace its contents with **default.conf** content.i tried replacing **default_server** with **localhost** as well but nothing helped.My spring boot application is running on port 8080.

Comment: Why do you need `nginx` in this case? If you really need it "Docker way" enforce you to move `nginx` and `spring application` to separate containers.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` inside your docker container (where nginx is running) is not pointing at your host's loopback interface, but at the containers' loopback device. You need to change the `proxy_pass` configuration in order to use your hosts' ip address (plus, ensure that your spring boot application is listening to 0.0.0.0 and not only localhost).

Comment: so what you are saying is server_name should be my machine ip and 
proxy pass should be like this . `proxy_pass http://$host:8080/testing;`

Comment: Not sure about the `/testing` at the end (depends on your sping boot application), but the hostname is obviously wrong if set to `localhost`.

Comment: i was able to solve this after removing `server_name` and replacing proxy_pass with `proxy_pass http://127:0:0:1:8080/testing` . but i cant add `$host`in this line . can u tell  mw why.